# Where, and what, is Elonei Mamre? And who is Mamre?

Tags: vayera, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha, parashat-chaye-sara, genesis-bereishith

In Sefer Bereshit (specifically Parshat Lech Lecha, Vayera, and Chayei Sarah) the is a place called Elonei Mamre. This is usually translated something along the lines of "the trees of Mamre."

Where/what is this place? [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.18.1.2?lang=he) seems to indentify Mamre as a person. Who was Mamre?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ber. 13:18](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?action=displayanchor&pentid=P337#C239)

> Abram moved on. He came and settled in the **(1)Plains** of **(2)Mamre**, in **(3)Hebron**, and there he built an altar to God.

***(1)Plains***

Eloney Mamre in Hebrew. Others translate it, 'Terebinths of Mamre.' See note on Genesis 12:6. Josephus states that it was by an oak called Ogyges (Ancient One) (Antiquities 1:10:4; Wars 4:9:7).

***(2)Mamre***

An Amorite who was Abram's ally (Genesis 14:13). This area was later known as Kiryath HaArba (Genesis 35:27).

***(3)Hebron***

A well known city, some 18 miles west of the Dead Sea, not very far from Sodom. This would mean that Abram migrated some 28 miles southward from Bethel.

(Above notes are from living Torah linked above)

Mamreh was one of Avraham’s good friends, and he even gave him advice ([*מדרש חופת אליהו*](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Chuppah_of_Eliyahu,_Chuppat_Eliyahu_Rabbah.10))

Expanded reading in ***[Bereshit Rabba 42](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.42.8)***:

> וְהוּא שֹׁכֵן בְּאֵלֹנֵי מַמְרֵא, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה וְרַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה,
>   רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אָמַר בְּמֵשְׁרַיָא דְמַמְרֵא. וְרַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה
>   אָמַר בְּפָלָטִין דְּמַמְרֵא, עַל דַּעְתֵּיהּ דְּרַבִּי יְהוּדָה
>   אַתְרָא הוּא דִּשְׁמֵיהּ מַמְרֵא, עַל דַּעְתֵּיהּ דְּרַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה
>   גַּבְרָא הוּא דִּשְׁמֵיהּ מַמְרֵא. וְלָמָּה נִקְרָא שְׁמוֹ מַמְרֵא,
>   רַבִּי עֲזַרְיָה בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי סִימוֹן
>   שֶׁהִמְרָה פָּנִים בְּאַבְרָהָם, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁאָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ
>   בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְאַבְרָהָם לִמּוֹל, הָלַךְ וְנִמְלַךְ בִּשְׁלשֶׁת
>   אֹהֲבָיו, אָמַר לוֹ עָנֵר כְּבָר בֶּן מֵאָה שָׁנָה אַתָּה וְאַתָּה
>   הוֹלֵךְ וּמְצַעֵר אֶת עַצְמְךָ. אָמַר לוֹ אֶשְׁכּוֹל מַה אַתְּ הוֹלֵךְ
>   וּמְסַיֵּם אֶת עַצְמְךָ בֵּין שׂוֹנְאֶיךָ. אָמַר לוֹ מַמְרֵא אֱלֹהֶיךָ
>   שֶׁעָמַד לְךָ בְּכִבְשַׁן הָאֵשׁ וּבַמְּלָכִים וּבָרֵעָבוֹן,
>   וְהַדָּבָר הַזֶּה שֶׁאָמַר לְךָ לָמוּל אֵין אַתָּה שׁוֹמֵעַ לוֹ. אָמַר
>   לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אַתָּה נָתַתָּה לוֹ עֵצָה לָמוּל,
>   חַיֶּיךָ שֶׁאֵינִי נִגְלָה עָלָיו לֹא בַּפָּלָטִין שֶׁל עָנֵר וְלֹא
>   בַּפָּלָטִין שֶׁל אֶשְׁכּוֹל אֶלָּא בַּפָּלָטִין שֶׁלְּךָ, הֲדָא הוּא
>   דִכְתִיב (בראשית יח, א): וַיֵּרָא אֵלָיו ה' בְּאֵלֹנֵי מַמְרֵא.